# pip install on OS X Mavericks fails with error: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running the Python 2.7.5 version that came standard with OSX.

I have tried to install pip using sudo **easy_install pip** AND **python get-pip.py**

When I try to install pip I get the following error with easy_install:

```
Processing pip
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /Users/XXXX/pip/egg-dist-tmp-VtRwku
warning: no files found matching 'pip/cacert.pem'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
pip 1.6.dev1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

When I try to install pip with get-pip.py

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.6.dev1-py2.7.egg
```

- Nothing shows when I type pip help

Comment: I have installed setup tools and Xcode command line dev tools

Comment: My goal is to install packages (currently rpy2 and pyodbc)

Comment: `pip 1.6.dev1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth` check that you don't have any previous pip version installed. What is the output of `ls -la /usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @Salem
`lrwxr-xr-x    1 XXX  admin     30 Jun  2 12:55 pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.7/bin/pip`

`lrwxr-xr-x    1 XXX  admin     31 Jun  2 12:55 pip2 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.7/bin/pip2`

`lrwxr-xr-x    1 XXX  admin     33 Jun  2 12:55 pip2.7 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.7/bin/pip2.7`

Comment: When I go to /Cellar/python/... these files are not present

Comment: easy-install.pth contents:
`import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)`
`./setuptools-4.0-py2.7.egg` 
`./pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg` 

`/Users/XXXX/src/pyv8`

`import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:];` 

`p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert =p+len(new)`

Comment: Should I even have a version of python installed in /usr/local/lib? When I type python in terminal at the moment it runs python 2.7.5 located in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python

Comment: I think `Cellar` folder is used by homebrew. Maybe you installed it form there? If so you should be able to uninstall it. If those links really don't exist (`/usr/local/Cellar/python/...`) then you can remove them.

Comment: It is normal to have something in `/usr/local/bin` just pointing to somewhere else. It makes that executable available in the path (so when you type `python` the shell knows how to find it)

Answer (score 1):

@ mirra.p
the problem is probably you have two versions of python 2 installed on your PC in different locations and pip of one of the copies of python got removed somehow. so when you try to install the pip for a copy, system says that there is a pip already installed in another location and also the /usr/local/bin folde is also missing the pip file used to installed pip.

already installed pip file's location is this:

Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.6.dev1-py2.7.egg

i just solved this issue so i will try to explain it in a way so that beginners also understand it properly

copy the already installed pip file to the location where it is missing instead of installing it through commands as command will detect the already installed pip.

the solution is very simple:

run these commands in a terminal (command prompt) in Ubuntu

to get the location of the pip file already installed

> which pip

`cp <location provided by which pip> <location where to copy pip file>`

> cp /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip /usr/local/bin

i used the locations for mirra.p problem.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message and especially the additional diagnostics in comments mentioning `Cellar` indicate that you have installed another Python version using Homebrew.

*Probably* simply renaming `/usr/local/bin/pip` to something else will fix the immediate problem. I'll advise against removing it entirely, at least until you understand what precisely is wrong.

In more detail; to use the system Python, you have to undo whatever Homebrew did when it installed a second Python. For a start, you need to unset all the variables which `brew` installed (or made you install) in your `.bashrc` and other locations previously.

If you have orphaned symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` which point to locations where no command is installed any longer, you'll want to simply remove those (needs root access). This is a sign of a dirty uninstall; next time, follow the Homebrew instructions for how to remove it and the packages you installed with it.

In more detail, Howebrew will have done something like

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/something/something/python-2.7.3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

and if `/usr/local/Cellar/something/something` now no longer exists, attempting to write something there through the symlink will obviously fail. This seems to be exactly what the `pip` installer is attempting to do at the very end of the installation.

If you have removed Homebrew permanently, you can edit `.bashrc` and revert whatever changes Homebrew required there. Some settings may remain active in your already-running shell instances until the next reboot; if you want to fix those, read on.

To temporarily override settings, you can `unset` your `PYTHONPATH` to get back the system default behavior. If you have commands in `/usr/local/bin` shadowing the system default ones, you can temporarily set your `PATH` to prefer `/usr/bin` by simply prepending it (this is a temporary hack only);

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

The shell commands are suitable for Bash; if you use another shell, adapt accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting error: `/usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory` and `pip` already is installed, do following things to solve this problem:

1. Run `which pip`. It will give answer like :`/usr/local/bin`
2. just copy pip file in desired location

here,

```
cp /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin/pip
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: You can't copy a directory to a file. You will neederoot privileges to copy anythingtto `/usr/local/bin/pip` but even as root, `/usr/local/bin` is not a thing you can meaningfully copy to that location.

Comment: And if `/usr/local/bin/pip` is a symlink, who knows what you'll end up overwriting by mistake.